# Get the size of vocabulary in tensorflow tokenizer

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tokenize

How do I get the size of the vocabulary (of an unknown dataset) after tokenization?

That is the code:

```
f = open("parallel2200Tab.txt","r")
pairs = [line.strip().split("\t") for line in  f]
f.close()
docs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(pairs)

tokenizer = text.WhitespaceTokenizer()
tokenized_docs = docs.map(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x))
```

I need to know the size of the vocabulary to train my model.

Answer (score 1):

tokenized docs should be accessible like a dict so try:

```
print(len(tokenized_docs))
```

or to print it all out in a half-assed debug mode go for:

```
i = 0
for k,v in tokenized_docs.items():
    print("word: "+k)
    print("numeric token: "+v)
    i++
    print("token count: "+i)
```

Comment: Almost that. This "print(len(tokenized_docs))" is given the amount of sentences. I want the amount of different words inside the document